# Filtering huge JSON file in Node.js | Autocompletion for a weather app

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to make an autocompletion endpoint in my server, I have a huge json file with city names that I want to autocomplete to. But I don't know how to parse/filter it.

The json file I want to use is this: https://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/current.city.list.json.gz

Example data from the above json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 14256,
    "coord": {
      "lon": 48.570728,
      "lat": 34.790878
    },
    "country": "IR",
    "geoname": {
      "cl": "P",
      "code": "PPL",
      "parent": 132142
    },
    "langs": [
      {
        "de": "Azad Shahr"
      },
      {
        "fa": "آزادشهر"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Azadshahr",
    "stat": {
      "level": 1.0,
      "population": 514102
    },
    "stations": [
      {
        "id": 7030,
        "dist": 9,
        "kf": 1
      }
    ],
    "zoom": 10
  },
  ...
]
```

How would I go about returning the matched cities in the format below:

```
{
  "matches": [
      {"id": 12312, "name": "New York", "country": "USA"}
  ]
}
```

here is my current code:

```
import cities from "../../static/citynames.json"

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { searchTerm } = getQuery(event)
  if (!searchTerm) {
    return {
      matches: []
    }
  }

  const matching_cities = cities.filter(city => {
    const city_name = city.name.toLowerCase()
    const country_name = city.country.toLowerCase()

    return country_name.startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || city_name.startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  })

  return {
    matches: matching_cities
  }

})
```

this is the json file I use (converted from xlsx): https://openweathermap.org/storage/app/media/cities_list.xlsx

Example data from the above json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abidjan",
    "lon": -4.00167,
    "lat": 5.35444,
    "country": "Ivory Coast"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abu Dhabi",
    "lon": 54.39696,
    "lat": 24.45118,
    "country": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
  ...
]
```

This one does not have the id's and it's too small of a data sample.

Comment: What is a problem you're having? The code looks okay, but will have time complexity of O(n) in the worst case, meaning it will be very slow.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel, time is not the only issue. It simply wouldn't load the json file at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some optimizations in your code.

1. You should try to extract the unnecessary calculations to outside of the iteration. Like `searchTerm.toLowerCase();` you don't need to do this a million times.
2. You can avoid unnecessary calculations inside the iteration. You don't need to check the `city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm)` if the country already matches.
3. You may consider to use alternative methods to `startsWith()`, depending on the content of the array and search terms, one of the alternative methods may have more performance. Some benchmarks on [this link](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/12350/0/startswith-vs-test-vs-match-vs-indexof#latest_results_block).

```js
import cities from "../../static/citynames.json";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const {searchTerm} = getQuery(event);

  if (!searchTerm) {
    return {
      matches: [],
    };
  }

  const search = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

  const matching_cities = cities
    .filter(city => city.country.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)
      || city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search))
    .map(({id, name, country}) => ({id, name, country}));

  return {
    matches: matching_cities,
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with optimization I will be using them, but I would really appreciate an answer for the real question :).

Comment: @feusanc Added an array map after the filter, to answer your real question.